# String variable assignment not working C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am calling a *modal form* (`ss`) which displays all the stock codes for a given search criteria. The user selects an item

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{
    selectedStockDescription = dgv_StckSrchRes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    selectedStockCode = dgv_StckSrchRes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
        (selectedStockDescription), 
        "Add this item to the order?", 
         MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, 
         MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes) 
    {
        stockCode = selectedStockCode;
        stockDescription = selectedStockDescription;

        this.Close();                         
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.No) 
    { 
        this.Focus();
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) 
    {
        this.Close(); 
    } 
}
```

and the following two public strings are set in the *modal form*:

```
public string stockCode { get; set; }
public string stockDescription { get; set; }
```

In my *parent form*, I assign these values to two variables initialised at class level.

```
using (StockSearch ss = new StockSearch(selectedDept, txb_StockCode.Text))
{
    if (ss.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        stckCd = ss.stockCode;
    stockDescription = ss.stockDescription;

    SetFormProperties();
    PopulateStockInformation();
    GetLeadTimes();   
}
```

However only the `stockDescription` variable is setting.  The `stckCd` remains `null` even though the value on the right side - `ss.stockCode` - is populated. It just *isn't assigning* the value to `stckCd` and I need it in order to access this value elsewhere in my application. I have tried initialising them with a value but it doesn't fix it.

Can anyone enlighten me please?

Comment: Side note: `if (ss.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel) {stckCd = ss.stockCode; stockDescription = ss.stockDescription;}`

Comment: So the dialog result is `Cancel`?

Comment: Set a *breakpoint* on `stckCd = ss.stockCode;` do you enter it?

Comment: Are you cancelling the dialog? (so that the result of the dialog is `DialogResult.Cancel`, thus not executing your statement inside the if?) Does your dialog set DialogResult properly?

Comment: Parentheses FTW. That's why I use them even for 1-liners.

Comment: I am attempting to capture a successful selection from the modal form.  So if ShowDialog not-equal to DialogResult.Cancel -> Continue processing.  Am I misunderstanding the logic in what I have done?

Comment: The result does return from the modal form.  The public strings are populated so the selection part is working, I just can't seem to capture the code in the calling form....

Comment: @acn: I've added the relevant code (from the modal form); now your question (I hope) is not off topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on `StockSearch` (*modal form*) side: when closing `StockSearch` you should set `DialogResult`: there are *two* possible closings here - *cancel* (default behaviour) and *OK*.

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    selectedStockDescription = dgv_StckSrchRes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    selectedStockCode = dgv_StckSrchRes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
      (selectedStockDescription), 
      "Add this item to the order?", 
       MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, 
       MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes) {
      // Confirmed: close the form WITH the choice made (DialogResult.OK)
      stockCode = selectedStockCode;
      stockDescription = selectedStockDescription;

      // this.Close();                     // <- cause of the misbehaviour           
      this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; // <- not Close (with cancel) but with OK
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.No)  
      // Not confirmed: keep on selecting 
      this.Focus();
    else // no need in "if": all the rest is Cancel 
      // Cancellation: close the form WITHOUT choice (DialogResult.Cancel)
      this.Close(); // <- Close with DialogResult.Cancel
  }
```

On the parent form side

```
   using (StockSearch ss = new StockSearch(selectedDept, txb_StockCode.Text)) {
     if (ss.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel) {
       stckCd = ss.stockCode;
       // You should not change stockDescription on DialogResult.Cancel  
       stockDescription = ss.stockDescription;  
     } 

     //TODO: it seems that these three calls should be within if as well
     SetFormProperties();
     PopulateStockInformation();
     GetLeadTimes();   
   }
```

Comment: I populate a DataGridView object on my modal form.  The user selection is set on an onclick event at which point a msg box asks for confirmation of the selection.

Comment: @acn: and after the confirmation (and maybe validation) you should close the modal form with `DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;`

Comment: Thank you Dmitry.  I'm not sure what I have done wrong but it appears my question has been closed for being off topic.  Maybe I'll just buy a book. ;-/

Comment: @acn: Your question id not *off topic*, but you hasn't provided all the relevant code (the error was in `dataGridView1_CellContentClick` method)

Comment: Dmitry - Thank you so much for helping me.  That's resolved my problem - you're a star! :-)

Comment: @acn: You are welcome! Next time, please, provide more code and your  question will be answerd sooner without downvotes and closing